# Is it possible to refactor React-Navigator Elements?

Tags: react-native, refactoring, react-navigation, ecmascript-2016

I'm learning the ropes with React Native and React Navigator at the moment and I've come across something in development where I feel like I want to implement the DRY (don't repeat yourself) technique.

Here's my component code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
      welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
      auth: { screen: AuthScreen },
      main: { 
        screen: TabNavigator({
          map: { screen: MapScreen },
          deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
          review: {
            screen: StackNavigator({
              review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
              settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
            })
          }
        }, { 
          tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
          lazyLoad: true,
          animationEnabled: false,
          swipeEnabled: false
        })
      }
    }, {
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      lazyLoad: true,
      animationEnabled: false,
      swipeEnabled: false  
    });

    return <MainNavigator />;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have the following chunk of repeatable code:

```
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
lazyLoad: true,
animationEnabled: false,
swipeEnabled: false
```

I tried to refactor the same way that you would do styles in React components like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
      welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
      auth: { screen: AuthScreen },
      main: { 
        screen: TabNavigator({
          map: { screen: MapScreen },
          deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
          review: {
            screen: StackNavigator({
              review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
              settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
            })
          }
        }, { defaultTabStyles })
      }
    }, { defaultTabStyles });

    return <MainNavigator />;
  }
}

const defaultTabStyles = {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  lazyLoad: true,
  animationEnabled: false,
  swipeEnabled: false
};
```

As you can see, this is a much cleaner way of doing things if it would work. But it doesn't work, so is there a way of refactoring this correctly or do I need to stick with my original implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are wrapping your `defaultTabStyles` object in curly braces, which thanks to the ES6 object property shorthand creates the following object:

```js
{
  defaultTabStyles:
    {
      animationEnabled: false,
      lazeLoad: true,
      swipeEnabled: false,
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    },
}
```

Which contains none of the keys the navigator is looking for. Try removing the curly braces:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
      welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
      auth: { screen: AuthScreen },
      main: { 
        screen: TabNavigator({
          map: { screen: MapScreen },
          deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
          review: {
            screen: StackNavigator({
              review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
              settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
            })
          }
        }, defaultTabStyles) // instead of { defaultTabStyles }
      }
    }, defaultTabStyles);  // instead of { defaultTabStyles }

    return <MainNavigator />;
  }
}

const defaultTabStyles = {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  lazyLoad: true,
  animationEnabled: false,
  swipeEnabled: false
};
```

Furthermore, to keep it DRY further down the road, you can override default options for specific navigators using spread syntax:

```js
const mainScreenTabStyles = {
  ...defaultTabStyles,
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
}
```